# What is the probability distribution of T in this process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, binomial-distribution

I have Markov Chain $\{X_n\}$ and the states $S=\{0,1,2\}$, with the probability matrix

$$P= \Bigg [\matrix {p &q &0\\0&p&q\\0&0&1} \Bigg] \quad where \quad p \in [0,1)$$
I want to find the probablity distribution of getting
$$T=inf\{ n \leq 0: X_n=2 \}$$
to state 2 when the chain starts from state 0, i.e. $X_0=0$. And to find
$$E[T|X_0=1]$$.

I started by thinking about the distribution. And used the fact that the sum $Z=X_1+...+X_n$ independent r.v. geometrically distribiuted  fllows negatively binomial distribution, so I wrote:
$$P(Z=k|X_0)=\Bigg(\matrix{k-1\\k-d}\Bigg) (1-p)^{d}p^{k-d} \quad k \geq d.$$
And I dont know where to go next. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Start finding $$E[T|X_0=1]$$

Comment: @N74 I don't know how without knowing what distribution T is.

Comment: You know $E[T|X_0=2]=0$. Now, from $X_0=1$ you stay in $1$ with probability $p$ and go in $2$ with probability $q$. So you can write an expression for $E[T|X_0=1]$ in terms of $p$, $q$ and $E[T|X_{n+1}=2]=E[T|X_0=2]$.